# VBA xlDown Range in Vlookup Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA vlookup function contained within a larger macro, but am now being asked to adapt it for a table with an unknown number of rows. What this line does is paste the result of a VLookup into a cell. This line works fine for the fixed size table of 270 rows:

```
 With Worksheets("Dashboard")
.Range("d2").Offset(x, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
   .Range("c2").Offset(x, 0), Worksheets("Backend").Range("a2:b271"), 2, False)
```

What I need to change is the "Worksheets("Backend").range("a2:b271")" portion of the line to a dynamically sized table. I'm not too familiar with ranges within an Excel VBA standpoint.

What I have is this:

```
With Worksheets("Dashboard")
.Range("d2").Offset(x, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
         .Range("c2").Offset(x, 0), _
         Worksheets("Backend").Range("a2", .Range("b2").End(xlDown)), 2, False)
```

Basically, I know that the table will be from A:B, but I'm trying to get it to select the entirety of rows A2:B???.

I greatly appreciate whomever is the quickest to solve this rookie mistake.

Comment: It would help to include your `With...End With` statements otherwise it's difficult to tell what you're working with.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Man, do I wish I could find these in the search as quick as y'all ;)

Comment: It's just practice @idalsin. That and I use "site:staackoverflow.com [search terms]" in google instead of built in search function.

Comment: minor point that avoids the issue (but only in this case - identifying the correct range is the general and better solution) VLookup is perfectly fine being passed a range that is larger than necessary - it is 'intelligent' enough to ignore the blank part of the range e.g. passing in B2:B1000000 even if data is just in B2:B10 will not increase it's computation time (I think internally it might intersect it with say .UsedRange or something - pure speculation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim rng as Range

With Worksheets("Backend")
    Set rng = .Range( .Range("A2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp) )
End With

With Worksheets("Dashboard")

    .Range("d2").Offset(x, 0) = _
     Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("c2").Offset(x, 0), rng, 2, False)

End With
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly. Is this just a case where I should always name my ranges in advance, or is that a limitation of using a WorksheetFunction?

Comment: Not really naming ranges here, just using a varaible to make the code a bit less cluttered.  It is not required though.  Your original code was erroring becuase you were trying to reference a range across two sheets `Worksheets("Backend").Range("a2", .Range("b2").End(xlDown))` - here the `.Range("b2")` is referring to the sheet in your `With` statement.

Comment: Ah, the with killed it. That makes a lot more sense to me then for why it was tossing an error. Thanks!